# Making Http Call from c#

Tags: c#

There is a classic asp application which makes calls to .shtml files using AspHttp.Conn. It makes the request by appending all the input and also reads the response by reading the values in the response by length.
Here is the example

```
strMessage= "test.shtml"
Set HttpObj = Server.CreateObject("AspHTTP.Conn")
HttpObj.Url = url & strMessage
HttpObj.PostData = "testarea=" & strRequestData
HttpObj.TimeOut = 60
HttpObj.RequestMethod = "post"
strResponseData = HttpObj.GetURL

Response.Write  Mid(strResponseData,3,1)
Response.Write  Mid(strResponseData,4,3)
```

If I need to rewrite this, what will be the best way to do this. I will be using MVC and will be rewriting the UI. what will be the best approach to make httpcall from c#?.  The backend to which the request will be sent will not be changed. Please suggest.

Comment: There are several ways, such as using an `HttpClient` object or a `WebRequest` object.  And there are many examples to be found on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .Net Framework 4.5 you can make request as

```
public static async Task<int> HtmlLoadAsync(string url/*, bool addUserAgent = false*/)
{
    try
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        //if (addUserAgent)                 OPTIONAL 
        //{
        //    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd(UserAgent);
        //}
        //client.Timeout = TimeOut;
        var response = client.GetStringAsync(url); //here you can change client method according to your required outpu
        var urlContents = await response;            
        // process urlContents now
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now call it as

```
private async void Process()
{
  await HtmlLoadAsync("http://....");
}
```

**Note:** You must have to add reference `System.Net.Http`